# Unsubscribe Newsletter

Tags: users, notifications

I was implemented "simplenews_register" module in my drupal project. so, Whenever user want to register in this site He has to enter his user name,email address,password and at the same time he want to subscribe any existing newsletter  then he check the related newsletter  check box. Then, automatically user will receive one mail regarding to subscribe link . So, he want to subscribe then he will click that link .

Here my requirement is if user has been subscribed any newsletter then automatically he has to receive "Unsubscribe" link . So, for this requirement what I have to do please guide me.

Comment: Hello Narendra. What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Unsubscribe links are automatically included when emails are sent via simplenews.

By the way, if you're using simplenews-2.x, you don't need the simplenews_register module; that functionality is included.